# Как задать определенную громкость html5 аудиоплеерам?

Tags: mediaplayer, аудио, html5, плеер

Приветствую.
Прошу помощи у знатоков в данной сфере, ибо не много учил об аудиотегах плееров html5.

```
<audio controls autoplay>
    <source src="music.mp3">
</audio>
```

У меня на сайте играет фоновая музыка, когда открываешь сайт, музыка играет на всю громкость, это плохо, особенно когда к компьютеру подключены самбуферы o_0 )) 
Есть возможность указать определенную громкость?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://habrahabr.ru/post/148202/ - вот здесь хорошо по этому поводу описано